# IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python

Line 6 of this code produces a "IndexError: string index out of range". I assume that when I ask "if line[6] != None" there is no content in the line, but I can not figure out why. I have also tried using !='', but the problem is before that.

```
import csv
dict1={} 
list1 = csv.reader(open('014850_D_AA_20070207.txt'), delimiter='\t')
list1.next()    # skips the headers
for line in list1:
    if line[6] != None:
        dict1[line[0]]= (line[6] + ", " + line[11])
    else:
        continue    
print dict1
```

Comment: You haven't actually provided any code.

Comment: string indexes start at 0, so you might be looking for `line[5]`.

Comment: Thanks, it is line[6], and I failed to mention the text file is tab delimited, and results in a list with 14 elements, so there is always a position "6", I am just trying to skip the lines when line[6] is empty.

Comment: @user1748925: it looks like your file does not *always* contain 14 values on a line. Check the length of the line too. Note; testing for `None` is best done with `something is not None` or `something is None`.

Answer (score 3):

1. Python indexing is zero-based, so `line[6]` accesses the 7th element of `line`. In this case, `line` doesn't have seven elements, so it fails.
2. `if line[6] != None` isn't the right way to check if a line has no content. Use `if len(line) < 7` instead.
3. `csv.DictReader` is a much nicer interface for reading CSV files with header rows. Iterating over it gives you the rows as dictionaries with the corresponding header items as keys, which makes the code a lot more understandable (compared to using magic indices).

Comment: +1 for suggesting an answer as well as the better alternative.

Comment: I would love to use cdv.DictReader. I am trying to produce a dictionary with keys at from position"0" and values from position "6" and "11". I apologize, but was not able to figureout how to do that.I would also still need to skip those with empty values from position "6".

Comment: Thanks for all the advice. I was able to solve my problem using csv.DictReader as below: import csv
dictPI = {}
dictGS = {}
fh = open('014850_D_AA_20070207.txt')
for line in csv.DictReader(fh, delimiter='\t'):
    ProbeID = line['ProbeID']
    GeneSymbol = line['GeneSymbol']
    Description = line['Description']
    if GeneSymbol != '':
        dictPI[ProbeID] = GeneSymbol, Description
        dictGS.setdefault(GeneSymbol, []).append(ProbeID)

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace line 6 with:

```
if len(line) > 6:
```

but probaly

```
if len(line) > 11:
```

is better since you use line[11] below.

When you test line[6] to be == to None you already are trying to access the seventh element of line. This gives you an index error if the line contains less than 7 characters

Answer (score 0):

to avoid that put that in a 'try' block and use string.find() for example

[-1] is for getting the last char in a string

also stuff like

```
else:
 continue
```

is unusual

I almost forgot to say: if string[5] != None:
will raise a indexerror of course because if its none it will be out of range

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the helpful ideas. I was able to solve my problem using the csv.DictReader as below:

```
import csv
dictPI = {}
dictGS = {}
fh = open('014850_D_AA_20070207.txt')
for line in csv.DictReader(fh, delimiter='\t'):
    ProbeID = line['ProbeID']
    GeneSymbol = line['GeneSymbol']
    Description = line['Description']
    if GeneSymbol != '':
        dictPI[ProbeID] = GeneSymbol, Description
        dictGS.setdefault(GeneSymbol, []).append(ProbeID)
```